# Efficient searching for substrings in SQL [Python/SQLite]

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have two SQLite tables (`list1` and `list2`) each with only one text column (`val`). I want efficiently search all combinations, where `list2.value` can be substring in `list1.value`.

Currently I have this solution:

```
import sqlite3

list1 = ["this is string1", "this is string2", "this is string3"]
list2 = ["string1", "string2"]

in_memory = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
c = in_memory.cursor()
c.execute('CREATE TABLE list1 (val text NOT NULL)')
c.execute('CREATE TABLE list2 (val text NOT NULL)')

for v in list1:
    c.execute("INSERT INTO list1 VALUES (?)", (v, ))

for v in list2:
    c.execute("INSERT INTO list2 VALUES (?)", (v, ))

l = [*c.execute("SELECT list1.val, list2.val FROM list1, list2 WHERE instr(list1.val, list2.val)")]
print(l)
```

Prints correctly:

```
[('this is string1', 'string1'), ('this is string2', 'string2')]
```

Is there more effective SQL solution than iterating over each `list1.val` and `list2.val` combination and search if there's substring?

Comment: [Full Text Search](https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html) might be of interest.

Comment: @Shawn Yes, I looked at it but couldn't get it to work (I'm SQL beginner). Could you please provide an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can phrase this as a single query:

```
select l1.value, l2.value
from list1 l1 join
     list2 l2
     on l1.val like '%' || l2.val || '%';
```

Doing the loop inside the database is slightly more efficient that doing the loop yourself -- because only matching rows are returned and you don't have the overhead of multiple queries.

However, this will still be doing nested loops.   Such a query cannot take advantage of traditional indexes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I looked at FTS5 SQLite extension, but I couldn't get it work. Is it possible to use this SQLite full-text index in this case?

Comment: @AndrejKesely . . . Possibly not.  For instance, full text search looks for *words* in the text, and your code is looking for generic strings.  I also think that `match` requires that the pattern be a constant -- which would suggest your approach of a nest-loop in the application level.

Comment: *" Possibly not full text search looks for words in the text, and your code is looking for generic strings. "*  @AndrejKesely  *" 3.2. FTS5 Phrases 
FTS queries are made up of phrases. A phrase is an ordered list of one or more tokens."* see [manual](https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html) the search just not only have to be a "word" SQLite supports searching generic strings also.